# How do I stop the result of %@EXEC[] being included in my prompt?

Tags: prompt

Per commentary to https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9623/1932:

I have tried `%@EXEC[]` to run a BTM from my prompt in 4DOS/4OS2/4NT/Take Command/TCC, but the return value of the BTM ends up in the prompt.
Can I stop that from happening?  How?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.  They are both in the doco.

- Prefix the BTM with `@`.  I have a vague memory that this was not available in some very old versions of these command interpreters.
- Use `$h` to backspace over the `0`.  This presumes that the exit code of the script in human-readable form is always one character long, and is therefore the less preferable mechanism.

## Further reading

- [`%@EXEC[]`](https://jpsoft.com/help/f_exec.htm).  *Variables and functions*.  JP Software.
- [`PROMPT`](https://jpsoft.com/help/prompt.htm).  *Commands*.  JP Software.